# Appending a Random Access File

Tags: c++, arrays, char, random-access

I'm having problems appending to a random-access file. I don't seem to be able to overwrite a field within the file. Instead, I'm only appending to the file, and leaving the old name intact.

```
fstream Airline("AirLine.text", ios::out | ios::in | ios::app | ios::binary); 
if(!Airline)
{
    cout << "File Could not be opened." << endl;  
    system("PAUSE");
    exit (1);
}

cout << "Enter Seat Number to Update" << "(1 to 100, 0 to end)?";

NewPassenger passenger;
cin >> passenger.seat_number;

while (0 < passenger.seat_number && passenger.seat_number <= 100)
{
    Airline.seekp((passenger.seat_number - 1 ) * sizeof(NewPassenger));
    Airline.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&passenger), sizeof(NewPassenger));

    cout << " Found Record. Now Enter New Name:";
    cin >> passenger.name;

    Airline.seekg((passenger.seat_number - 1 ) * sizeof(NewPassenger),ios::beg);
    Airline.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&passenger), sizeof(NewPassenger));

    cout << "\nEnter Seat Number: ?";
    cin >> passenger.seat_number;
}

Airline.close();
cout << endl;
```

`NewPassenger` is defined as follows:

```
struct NewPassenger
{ 
    int seat_number;
    char name[20];
    char onward[3];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fstream Airline("AirLine.text", ios::out | ios::in | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

Looking at [cplusplus.com on `fstream::open`](http://app%09%28append%29%20Set%20the%20stream%27s%20position%20indicator%20to%20the%20end%20of%20the%20stream%20before%20each%20output%20operation.) I see the append flag described as

> app   (append) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream ***before each output operation***.

(Emphasis added). It looks like you are getting the behavior you asked for. Perhaps you wanted

> ate   (at end) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream on opening.

Comment: Thank you I change app to ate and it worked.. this was doing my head in for about 4hours...

Answer (score 0):

Use `seekg` with the correct positional argument:

```
seekg(abs_pos, std::ios::beg);  // seek relative to the beginning
```

The default is `std::ios::cur`, i.e. relative to the current position.

Same for `seekp`.

---

<sub>Concretely, say this:</sub>

```
Airline.seekp((passenger.seat_number - 1 ) * sizeof(Newpassenger), std::ios::beg);
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: with my Code seekp the SeatNumber to -1 then go to the SeatNumber i entered and then it should replace the passengers name with the passengers name i entered. can you show the seekg in more code ?

Comment: Leave your code just as it is, only add the second argument to the seek commands.

Comment: ok i added it to the end. if im following you but it told me undeclared identifier 'abs_pos'           [code]Airline.seekg((passenger.seat_number - 1 ) * sizeof(Newpassenger),(abs_pos,ios::beg));[/code]

Comment: No no -- I only have you an *example*. You're supposed to put your own code instead of `abs_pos`, like so: Airline.seekp((passenger.seat_number - 1 ) * sizeof(Newpassenger), std::ios::beg);`. I'll edit the post...

Comment: OK.. But i am using using namespace std

Comment: @user1058717 then omit `std::` from `std::ios::beg`. That said, `using namespace std;` is bad.

Comment: ok, it doesnt work either way i have it it still adding the New name to end of file.